# Store the query string parameter in session value and use it once user logged in

Tags: functions

I tried to store the query parameter in session value and use it once user logged in and destory after that
For example

https://example.com/requesttok=https://filelink.com/file.pdf

```
$_SESSION['query_param'] =  $_GET['requesttok'];
if($user_loggedin){
//token generation code
//appending token to the file pdf and redirect to file pdf
wp_redirect(https://filelink.com/file.pdf?token=asdfasdfasdfasdfadf)
}
```